# Valid timestamp format for PostgreSql

Tags: sql, database, postgresql

For example: 2000-99-00 is valid timestamp w\o time zone value for PostgreSQL db column? Or max\min for days is: 01,31; for months 01,12?

Comment: Why you do not try it out?

Comment: What happened when you tried?

Comment: well, i do not have such possibility currently :)

Comment: https://dbfiddle.uk/btGcOH30

Comment: What month (or day) should 99 and 00 represent?

Answer (score 0):

`2000-99-00` is not a valid timestamp in PostgreSQL, nor is it in any standard, terrestrial system. Your suggested max/min is an oversimplification - the system validates the input based on the actual month lengths and leap years [between 4713 BC and 294276 AD](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/datatype-datetime.html#DATATYPE-DATETIME-TABLE).

```sql
--year 2000 was a leap year so February had 29 days
select '2000-02-29'::timestamp;
--      timestamp
-----------------------
-- 2000-02-29 00:00:00

--year 2001 was not a leap year so February had 28 days
select '2001-02-29'::timestamp;
--ERROR:  date/time field value out of range: "2001-02-29"
--LINE 1: select '2001-02-29'::timestamp;
--               ^

select '2000-99-00'::timestamp;
--ERROR:  date/time field value out of range: "2000-99-00"
--LINE 1: select '2000-99-00'::timestamp;
--               ^
--HINT:  Perhaps you need a different "datestyle" setting.
```

If you're dealing with non-standard format, you can set a mask in [`to_timestamp()`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-formatting.html#id-1.5.8.14.4.2.2.6.1.1.1). You can also set a default input/output format in [`datestyle`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/15/runtime-config-client.html#GUC-DATESTYLE) setting.

For most popular RDBMS, if you just want to run a quick test without having to set up your own cluster, you can use online tools: [dbfiddle.uk](https://dbfiddle.uk/fi-p-uPT), [db-fiddle.com](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/51LeHcKHtFk4NoPBMzRMRF/0), [sqlfiddle.com](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/9eecb/100488)